# font rendering is too ugly on Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, fonts

every one 
like most of developer web developer i  hate ie, buts many people still use it ,
my problem is the text on ie is really ugly , on other modern browser is clean and clear
any solution js or css to fix this without modifying the browser setup ?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text in newer versions of IE should support ClearType, however some animations in jQuery and JavaScript cause dodgy opacity issues with ClearType.

If you are talking about IE6 and Windows XP - could I suggest this:
http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2009/11/29/how-to-detect-font-smoothing-using-javascript/

This blog is about detecting whether the client is using ClearType.